# What does char * mean

Tags: c++, c, char

So...say I had a function like this...

```
int function( const char *c )
{
 //do something with the char *c here...
}
```

what does `char *c` mean?  I know about chars in general I think but I don't get what the * does...or how it changes the meaning.

Comment: It's a pointer.  You need to learn this from a book or a lecture, it's not something that can be explained in a few lines if you don't already understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that this is a pointer to data of type char.

Comment: "Pointer of type char" is unusual terminology, and perhaps a bit confusing. "Pointer to char", or even "pointer of type pointer-to-char" would be better.

Answer (score 6):

`char *c` means that c is a pointer.  The value that c points to is a character.

So you can say `char a = *c`.

`const` on the other hand in this example says that the value c points to cannot be changed.
So you can say `c = &a`, but you cannot say `*c = 'x'`.  If you want a const pointer to a const character you would have to say `const char* const c`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pointer to a character. You might want to read up about pointers in C, there are about a bazillion pages out there to help you do that. For example, http://boredzo.org/pointers/.

Answer (score 2):

Pointer to a char. That is, it holds the address at which a char is located.

Answer (score 2):

Thats a `pointer-to-char`. Now that you know this, you should read this:

[About character pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752401/about-character-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

It means the argument should be a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) to a character.

You would dereference it with `*` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [Const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.9) page to get a good idea on pointer and const.

Answer (score 1):

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/  is the best resource that I have come across to learn about pointers in C . Read all the pointer related pdfs and also watch the binky pointer video.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointer to a `char` type. For example, this function can take the address of a char and modify the char, or a copy of a pointer, which points to an string. Here's what I mean:

```
char c = 'a';
f( &c );
```

this passes the address of `c` so that the function will be able to change the `c` char.

```
char* str = "some string";
f( str );
```

This passes "some string" to `f`, but `f` cannot modify `str`.

It's a really basic thing for c++, that higher-level languages (such as Java or Python) don't have.